# Function returning none when trying to get data from dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm following a tutorial at codecademy.com, and for some reason I can't understand, my program isn't returning the expected value, but is returning the value "none" instead.

I can't understand why. Would you mind taking a look?

The dictionaries I am using are:

```
lloyd = { "name": "Lloyd",
         "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
         "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
         "tests": [75.0, 90.0] }
alice = { "name": "Alice",
          "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
          "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
          "tests": [89.0, 97.0] }
tyler = { "name": "Tyler",
          "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
          "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
          "tests": [100.0, 100.0] }
```

And I tried the following functions:

```
def average(x):
    return sum(x)/len(x)

def get_average(x):
    a = (sum(x['homework'])/len(x['homework']) * 0.1 + 
         sum(x['quizzes'])/len(x['quizzes']) * 0.3 + 
         sum(x['tests'])/len(x['tests']) * 0.6)
    return a

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score <= 80 and score < 90:
        return "B"
    elif score <= 70 and score < 80:
        return "C"
    elif score <= 60 and score < 70:
        return "D"
    elif score < 60:
        return "F"

print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))
```

Comment: These things are usually easy to debug with a simple print statement... (e.g. `print score` at the top of `get_letter_grade`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your comparison logic is broken. This:

```
elif score <= 80 and score < 90:
```

says "if the score is less than or equal to 80, *and* less than 90"... So if the score is 80.55, that will never be true. You mean to say "if the score is *more than* 80 and less than 90".

The usual way to write that in Python is like this:

```
elif 80 <= score < 90:
```

Comment: It's also important to note that a function that does not return a value implicitly returns `None`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mistake in your `get_letter_grade` function: you used `>=` when you meant `<=` three times. A fixed (and slightly neater) version:

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif 80 <= score < 90:
        return "B"
    elif 70 <= score < 80:
        return "C"
    elif 60 <= score < 70:
        return "D"
    elif score < 60:
        return "F"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to think about the problem: **let a data structure do most of the work**.

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    grades = [('A', 90), ('B', 80), ('C', 70), ('D', 60), ('F', 0)]
    for g, s in grades:
        if score >= s: return g
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a problem with your function, it is checking if it is `<= 80` and `<90` where it should check if it is `>=80`, the fixed function will be:

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80 and score < 90:
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70 and score < 80:
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60 and score < 70:
        return "D"
    elif score < 60:
        return "F"
```

Answer (score 0):

The`if/elif`logic in the `get_letter_grade()` function is flawed. You can simplify and correct it by realizing you only need to check the next higher value to see if the score is above that to know what to`return`in each succeeding`if`because any previous one has already checked for levels above that. Here's what I mean:

```
def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >= 80:  # we also know it's < 90 because the prior if failed
        return "B"
    elif score >= 70:  # we also know it's < 80 because all the prior ifs failed
        return "C"
    elif score >= 60:  # we also know it's < 70 because all the prior ifs failed
        return "D"
    else:              # we know it's < 60 because all the prior ifs failed
        return "F"
```

Note also that if all`elif`s fail, the function will return an`"F"`because the last clause is an`else`not an`elif`like the preceding ones. This prevents the function from ever returning`None`, which is effectively what happens if a function doesn't explicitly execute a`return`with another value before "falling of the end".